# How to increase job order finish days column value in SQL SERVER by 1 automatic every day based on condition?

Tags: sql-server

I have a job orders system and when i create new job order i have the following columns order date , order status (open or close) , expected days column for example 5 days to finish this order and i have the actual days column this column actual days default value = 0 .
I need to create trigger to increment the value of column actual days by 1 daily every new day automatically if the job order open.
How can i do this trigger daily increment and update the value when new day start at 12 midnight ?
I am using SQL SERVER.

This is my table:

```
CREATE TABLE [Documents_followup](
    [Doc_id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Document_subject] [nvarchar](200) NULL,
    [Date] [datetime] NULL,
    [Document_number] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Doc_place_id] [int] NULL,
    [Doc_expect_time] [int] NULL,
    [Doc_finish_time] [int] NULL,
    [DocStatus_id] [int] NULL,
    [Notes] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [user_id] [int] NULL)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a trigger, you can just add a computed column. I would just use the `datediff` function.

```
select
   *,
   actual_days = datediff(day,order_date,getdate())
from YourTable
```

Now this doesn't work for *jobs only open* but you aren't accounting for *when* the job is closed. I suppose that's what the `actual_days` is supposed to do... add to the `order_date` to figure out when it closed. Instead, I would get rid of the `actual_days` column and just add a `close_date` column that can be updated whenever the `order_status` changes from open to close. Then, you can use the same `datediff` logic.

This makes more sense than writing a job that updates your table everyday. Without something to *trigger* the `TRIGGER` the update wouldn't happen. Besides it would be slow to do this RBAR so if you really can't change the design, then just use a SQL Agent Job to do this in batch.

```
update yourtable
set actual_days = datediff(day,order_date,getdate())
where order_status = 'open
```

You'll schedule that to run everyday or whatever... but again, it wouldn't be accurate if a job closes after you run that until the next day's run.

The other option is to *only* update the `actual_days` once the order is closed. This would allow you to use a trigger, or just include it in your `update statement` For example, a boiler plate for closing the ticket

```
create proc usp_closeTicket (@order_no int)
as
update mytable
set 
   order_status = 'closed'
   ,actual_days = datediff(day,order_date,getdate())
where order_no = @order_no
```

Of course you need to use proper error handling and what not. [Check our Erland's blog for that.](http://www.sommarskog.se/error_handling/Part1.html)

**Edit, now that you added the DDL**

Nothing is different than my suggestions above. Mainly I would use the `UPDATE` statement instead of a trigger which would change to this using your column names:

```
create proc usp_closeTicket (@order_no int)
as
update Documents_followup
set 
   DocStatus_id = 1 --or what ever signifies closed
   ,Doc_finish_time= datediff(day,[Date],getdate())
where Doc_id = @order_no
```

Comment: this is select command ? How to add computed column it will update automatically daily my column Doc_finish_time?

Comment: read the edited answer @Abdullah and you never said that you had a doc_finish_time.

Comment: doc_finish_time is the actual days

Comment: I will close the order from the application , just i need to update daily the Doc_finish_time , I executed the update command and i will create batch to run the update command daily midnight  the update command works thanks . I cannot vote for correct answer because i don't have 15 reputation.